# Kubernetes Prometheus metric for HPA (horizontal pod autoscaler) `currentCPUUtilizationPercentage`?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator, hpa

On a Kubernetes cluster with CoreOS Prometheus Operator scraping all standard cluster metrics, what Prometheus metric would show me the `currentCPUUtilizationPercentage` value for a simple HPA (horizontal pod autoscaler)?

If I setup a simple hpa like:

```sh
$ kubectl autoscale deployment php-apache --cpu-percent=30 --min=3 --max=10
```

And then if I do `kubectl get hpa php-apache -o yaml` I see something like:

```yaml
spec:
  maxReplicas: 10
  minReplicas: 3
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 30
  ...
status:
  currentCPUUtilizationPercentage: 28
  currentReplicas: 9
  desiredReplicas: 9
  ...
```

I want to see that `currentCPUUtilizationPercentage` in Prometheus. I've done a bunch of Prometheus queries to look for this.

I've searched all metrics tagged `{hpa="php-apache"}` and I see many hpa metrics, but not the metric I'm looking or. I can see `kube_hpa_spec_target_metric` set to 30 and I can see current status metrics like `kube_hpa_status_condition` but not the current cpu metric value that I want to see.

I've searched all metrics tagged `{metric_name="cpu"}` and only see `kube_hpa_spec_target_metric`

I've searched all container and pod related metrics tagged `{container="my-container-name"}` and `{pod=~"my-pod-prefix.*"}` and I see several cpu related metrics like `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` abnd `container_spec_cpu_quota` but nothing similar to or nothing that seems to be able to be used in calculating the `currentCPUUtilizationPercentage` value that I'm looking for?

FYI, this is on Kubernetes 1.17.x and using a recent version of CoreOS Prometheus Operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly currentCPUUtilizationPercentage is a k8 internal metrics for HPA and not exposed directly  as a metrics you can **scrape** with Prometheus.
see https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/autoscaling/horizontal-pod-autoscaler.md#autoscaling-algorithm

you probably could **scrape** component of currentCPUUtilizationPercentage  metrics and create custom metrics to see it in Prometheus.